# python skipping elif statements

Tags: python-3.x

Q is a user input, but when ever I type any colour it gives me blue no matter what. What am I doing wrong?

```
if q == "blue" or "Blue":
  color="\33[0;34m"
elif q == "cyan" or "Cyan" or "light blue" or "Light Blue" or "light Blue" or "Light blue":
  color="\033[1;36m"
elif q == "white" or "White":
  color="\033[0;37m" 
elif q == "green" or "Green":
  color="\033[0;32m"
elif q == "orange" or "Orange":
  color ="\033[0;33m"
elif q == "pink" or "Pink":
  color = "\033[1;31m"
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this instead:

```
if (q == "blue") or (q == "Blue"):
  color="\33[0;34m"
elif (q == "cyan") or (q == "Cyan") or (q == "light blue") or (q == "Light Blue") or (q == "light Blue") or (q == "Light blue"):
  color="\033[1;36m"
elif (q == "white") or (q == "White"):
  color="\033[0;37m" 
elif (q == "green") or (q == "Green"):
  color="\033[0;32m"
elif (q == "orange") or (q == "Orange"):
  color ="\033[0;33m"
elif (q == "pink") or (q == "Pink"):
  color = "\033[1;31m"
```

As you can see the problem lies in how you laid out your conditions

What happened?

Your code processed `if q == "blue" or "Blue"` into `if "Blue"`  which ultimately becomes true

You can test the former with this:

```
q == "blue" or "Blue" #prints "Blue"
```

and the latter with

```
if 'Blue':
     print("A") # The output
else:
     print("B")
```

Comment: @AaurshA. You will have to post your code up for us to know whats up but sounds like a logical issue to me.

Answer (score 0):

`if q == "blue" or "Blue"` returns true. `if "Blue"` will return true. You're looking for `if q == "blue" or q == "Blue"` or better, `if q.lower() == "blue"`, or even better: `if q.lower() in ['cyan', 'light blue']:`

Comment: We've all made these sorts of oversights. :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the correct way of doing it is:

```
In [89]: if q in ["blue", "Blue"]:
    ...:   color="\33[0;34m"
    ...:   print(q)
    ...: elif q in ["cyan","Cyan","light blue","Light Blue","light Blue","Light blue"]:
    ...:   color="\033[1;36m"
    ...: elif q in ["white","White"]:
    ...:   color="\033[0;37m"
    ...: elif q in ["green","Green"]:
    ...:   color="\033[0;32m"
    ...: elif q in ["orange", "Orange"]:
    ...:   color ="\033[0;33m"
    ...: elif q in ["pink", "Pink"]:
    ...:   color = "\033[1;31m"
    ...:
```

compare the elements from a list of values. In your case you are just comparing the q with  one of the values.

Answer (score 0):

> whenever I type any colour it gives me blue no matter what

The reason is simple - Any non-None or non-zero value in python is a **Falsy** value and others are **True**.

So you have input `q = "Red"`:

`if q == "blue" or "Blue":`, it evaluates to `if False or True` which further simplifies to `if True`. Thus the first condition is always satisfied. And hence the flaw in your code.

To solve the problem, rephrase your code to

```
if q in ["blue", "Blue"]:
  color="\33[0;34m"
elif q in ["cyan", "Cyan", "light blue", "Light Blue", "light Blue", "Light blue"]:
  color="\033[1;36m"
elif q in ["white", "White"]:
  color="\033[0;37m" 
elif q in ["green", "Green"]:
  color="\033[0;32m"
elif q in ["orange", "Orange"]:
  color ="\033[0;33m"
elif q in ["pink", "Pink"]:
  color = "\033[1;31m"
```

This would help.

Although a good attempt would be to write the code as follows:

```
q = q.lower()
if q == "blue":
  color="\33[0;34m"
elif q in ["cyan", "light blue"]:
  color="\033[1;36m"
elif q == "white":
  color="\033[0;37m" 
elif q == "green":
  color="\033[0;32m"
elif q == "orange":
  color ="\033[0;33m"
elif  == "pink":
  color = "\033[1;31m"
```

***Note***: If you want to write less code and achieve more, you can drop the `if-else` construct and instead use dictionary as follows:

```
name2code = {"blue":"\33[0;34m", "white":"\033[0;37m", "light blue":"\33[0;36m", "cyan":"\033[0;36m","green":"\33[0;32m", "orange":"\033[0;33m","pink":"\33[0;31m"}

q_code = name2code[q.lower()]
```